# <ul> boostrap list renders differently on Safari

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-lists

I have simple unordered list in Bootstrap 4:

```
<ul>
 <li>line 1</li>
 <li>line 2</li>
 <li>line 3</li>
 <li>line 4</li>
 <li>line 5</li>
</ul>
```

with this custom CSS:

```
ul, ol {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

But they renders differently on Firefox and Safari

**Firefox**
[image]

**Safari**
[image]

I've noticed that Bootstrap uses ::marker pseudo element instead of ::before, can I change it so that is more compatible with Safari?

Comment: Read this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718688/rems-rendering-differently-between-chrome-and-firefox Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a Bootstrap problem. I found a few solutions that may work:

1. This could happen if the charset is not set right. Try to add `@charset "UTF-8";` in the first line of your CSS code.
2. Developers often use reset CSS to reset default paddings and margins to reduce browser inconsistencies. You can find simple reset CSS [here](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).
3. You could add custom bullet points with CSS by adding a `list-style: none;` to your `ul` element and then add a bullet with `::before` on `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with a browser bug in Safari. I found one at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/browser-bugs/ that relates to rem units (WebKit bug #156684).

Comment: It seems related to media queries, but I’m not sure what it means

Comment: Bootstrap uses media queries for responsive layouts (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/). Try specifying `font-size` for the `li` element and use `em` or `px` instead of `rem`.